# How to unit test if the method returns just "any" value of type double?

Tags: java

I'm trying to test my method that returns a double in java.

I'm using the `assertEquals` method to see if the method returns the correct double value.

**Example:**

```
assertEquals(23.5, obj.someMethod("some string "));
```

But how would I test if the method just returns a double, not a specific value?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to assert that `isNan()` is `false` for the result:

```
// I am assuming that the method returns java.lang.Object, so I added a cast
double res = (double)obj.someMethod("some string ");
assertFalse(Double.isNan(res));
```

This ensures that the value returned from the method is a `double` that represents a valid number (as opposed to an infinity or NaN).

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to declare the method with return type `double`. You don't need to test things the compiler can ensure.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the method returns some object, you don't know exact type, so just [Assert an object is a specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404650/assert-an-object-is-a-specific-type) with the `Double.class`

Comment: The method returns a value of type double

Comment: @TokugawaIeysu When what do you want to assert? If it declared as returning double, then how could it return anything else? So basically you want just `assertTrue(true)`? What's a point?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if(obj.someMethod("some string ") instanceof Double)
    { System.out.println("rejoice!"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using some additional libraries to make these types of assertions. For one, Junit interacts well with Hamcrest (https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) for writing custom 'matchers', so you could easily write your own 'isSomeDouble' assertion and use that. For example, JUnit comes with an 'assertThat' method that takes a Hamcrest Matcher as the second argument.

Per the following SO posts ([Assert an object is a specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404650/assert-an-object-is-a-specific-type) and [Creating a assertClass() method in JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958460/creating-a-assertclass-method-in-junit)), something like this ought to do it:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.instanceOf;

assertThat(obj, instanceOf(Double.class)); // or assertThat(Double.valueOf(obj), instanceOf(Double.class))
```